# Visualforce Page On Console View

Tags: apex, visualforce, case, service-cloud-console

Am trying to show simple visualforce page on the right side bar of the custom console layout.[image]

In the Visualforce page, am trying to show some text like below

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showChat="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
This is console view right side bar
</apex:page>
```

When I click on Preview button on the developer console, I can able to see the text what I have in Page level. But When I try to see in console view, it is showing **'undefined'**
[image]

I am wondering why it is not showing in console view.
Any help is appreciable thanks!.

Comment: does your profile have access to vf page

Comment: Yes I checked. I have access to vfp

Comment: That is weird, try again with clearing your browser history.